# Fail to install Nvidia driver in Linux

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I tried to install Nvidia driver in Ubuntu 16.04, I download the package from the official website and excute the command

```
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.183.run –no-opengl-files
```

However, An error happened with

```
/nvidia-installer: invalid option: "–no-opengl-files"

ERROR: Invalid commandline, please run `./nvidia-installer --help` for usage information.
```

Could somebody give me a solution?

Comment: The solution is not to shoot in your foot and NOT try to install drivers from a run files. There is a ton of manuals how to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Could you provide a link to the install instructions on the official website? There should likely be `--` (two [hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen)) instead of an [en dash](https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/) in the beginning of `–no-opengl-files`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the installed drivers by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo apt remove nvidia-*  
sudo apt autoremove
```

see which is the recommended driver for your Nvidia card by running:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If you want to install the driver automatically, run :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you want to install a specific driver, run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-<driver number>
```

Once the installation is finished, run `prime-select query` to check which graphic card is being used by your device.
If you want to change the graphic card used by your PC, run : `sudo prime-select <intel/ nvidia>`; choose between Nvidia and Intel graphic cards.
After that, restart your PC to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

You don't need a `run` file for that.

Another option is to use Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers GUI for that purpose.