# Issue to install Nvidia 2080 ti driver with Python

Tags: nvidia, python, pip, url

Good morning,
I actually have boring issue, trying to install the Nvidia 2080 ti driver on a Ubuntu 18-04 workstation.

I reinstalled a Ubuntu 18-04 workstation with a new partition schema. The seller suggested me to follow that procedure.

The first step worked fine after

```
sudo su -
```

Then after the title "use a repository for a packaged driver", it works fine as well until the command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-$(pyvidia)
```

it return me the following message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pyvidia",
>   line 11, in 
>       load_entry_point('pyvidia==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyvidia')()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvidia.py", line 468, in
>   __main
>       required_series = get_required_driver_series(pci_id)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvidia.py", line 370, in
>   get_required_driver_series
>       get_all_supported_devices()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvidia.py", line 250, in
>   get_all_supported_devices
>       __load_latest_version_numbers()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvidia.py", line 221, in
>   __load_latest_version_numbers
>       download_url = __get_download_url_for_tag(child)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvidia.py", line 164, in
>   __get_download_url_for_tag
>       dl_page = urllib2.urlopen(dl_page_link)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 467, in error
>       result = self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 654, in http_error_302
>       return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found Reading package lists...
>   Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done
>   Package 'nvidia' is not installed, so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.

I believe the point of interrest is around thoses line

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

but I do not understand what is looking and did I miss to do, (may be in relation with

> get_full_url

Did I miss to do something, or did I do something wrong?

Note, I also tried with pip3 without success.

Many thank for any help and suggestion will be appreciate.
Cheers

Comment: Check the steps described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121387/822295)